# REDIS: What does the number in the cluster_enabled mean? Is 0 true or is 1 true?

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, redis-cli

When you enter INFO in redis-cli, you get a field called `cluster_enabled`. It is set to `0` for me. Does this mean that cluster mode is enabled or not? I know this is basic but suprisingly the documentation just says `cluster_enabled: Indicate Redis cluster is enabled`

Comment: `1` means enabled, `0` means not enabled.

Comment: Cheers! Do you mind posting an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

`1` means enabled, `0` means not enabled as per Mark Setchells comment